# node.js upload and download pdf file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

**Framework**: node.js/express.js/busboy/gridfs-stream(mongodb)

I am using busboy to upload files and then use gridfs-stream to store files in mongodb gridfs.

```
                req.pipe(req.busboy);
                req.busboy.on('file', function (bus_fieldname, bus_file, bus_filename) {

                var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
                    filename: bus_filename,
                });

                bus_file.pipe(writestream);

                writestream.on('close', function (file) {
                    res.redirect('/xxxxx/');
                });
            });
```

Download is simple: Use gridfs-stream's createReadStream I read the contents from mongodb and then use the following code to send it to browser.

```
            gfs.findOne({_id: attachmentid}, function (err, file) {
            if (err || !file){
                res.send(404);
            }else{
                var fileName = file.filename;
                var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: attachmentid});
                var buffer = "";
                readstream.on("data", function (chunk) {
                    buffer += chunk;
                });

                // dump contents to buffer
                readstream.on("end", function () {
                    res.set("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                    res.send(buffer);
                });

            }
```

**Problem**: When I upload a 90kb pdf file, it uploads fine. I see the size is correct in mongodb. But when I download, the file size of the downloaded file is about 165kb. There is a mismatch. This does not happen with text files. Sure its something to do with data type.

can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe the gfs read stream to the response directly. This is what works for me

```
res.set("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileName);
var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: attachmentid});
readstream.pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Sasikanth said you can fix the problem with piping and that's the best approach.

But if you are wondering what's wrong with your current approach, then I suggest to read the [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) documentation.You are naming your variable as `buffer` but assigning string.

Then in your `data` callback you are adding string with Buffer. When you do that the `chunk` buffer is converted to string using it's `toString()` method. So your binary data is converted to utf8 encoded string and here it goes wrong. Since utf8 is multi-byte encoding the output size becomes large(I don't know the exact mechanism of this conversion).

So the right way to do is to keep it in buffers:

```
var buffers = [];
readstream.on("data", function (chunk) {
    buffers.push(chunk)
});


readstream.on("end", function () {
    res.set("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    res.send(Buffer.concat(buffers));
});
```